# Providing Hyper-V VMs with network through custom NAT in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, hyper-v, nat

I'm trying to set up a NAT on Windows 10 to provide Hyper-V VMs with access to both Internet and Cisco AnyConnect VPN configured on the host machine. In accordance with [this](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/hyper-v-on-windows/user-guide/setup-nat-network) manual I executed the following PowerShell script:

```
New-VMSwitch -SwitchName 'VM NAT switch' -SwitchType Internal
New-NetIPAddress -IPAddress '192.168.2.1' -PrefixLength 24 -InterfaceAlias 'vEthernet (VM NAT switch)'
New-NetNat -Name 'VM NAT' -InternalIPInterfaceAddressPrefix '192.168.2.0/24'
```

The script was successfully completed and `VM NAT Switch` was assigned to a VM. But the IP address the VM was provided with at startup was 169.254.x.x, not 192.168.2.x. Then I tried to configure network connection in the VM manually as 192.168.2.2/24, default gateway 192.168.2.1. The settings was accepted, but the network was still unreachable:
[image: ping result]

In the same time the network is reachable when Hyper-V Default Switch is used instead of my custom vSwitch. But I need to forward some ports through the NAT and I don't know how to do that for Default Switch.

What have I missed in the NAT configuration?

Comment: If you see 169.254.x.x addresses, generally assume those _weren't_ provided, i.e. there was no DHCP service or it wasn't working. They're link-local "autoconf" addresses.

Comment: @user1686 True. But the network stays unreachable even when the connection is configured manually with a proper IP address, gateway, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set a static IP for the Hyper-V VM's network adapter since you don't have a DHCP server providing IP addresses for your new internal Switch.
In the DNS- section, provide googles DNS 8.8.8.8

In short:

```
IP-address: 192.168.2.10
Netmask: 255.255.255.0
Gateway: 192.168.2.1

DNS 1: 8.8.8.8
DNS 2: 8.8.4.4
```

Good luck!